# Reading an unkown serialized object in Java

Tags: java, object, serialization

I have a server that crashed (Minecraft if you want to know), and some precious data were saved in a serialized object file. I did not succeed reading it with Java's ObjectInputStream. This is piece of code I found online edited a little. When I read the object, it throws an ClassNotFoundException.

```
//Part of it
ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
Object obj = objStream.readObject();
System.out.println("The Object : "+  obj);
objStream.close();
System.out.println("Deserializing Operation Completly Successfully.");
```

The problem is I don't know it's content at all. How do I know what are the fields and the methods are contained in this object?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.****.****.****.**** //CENSORED
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:602)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1589)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1494)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1748)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:593)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:979)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1327)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at main.ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:28)
```

**Edit:** I have decompiled it, and added all of it's packages to my src. Successfully read the object. But this DOES NOT ANSWER the question, the question remains;"how to read an unkown serialized object in Java.".

Comment: Please attach the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: If you have successfully read the object, you didn't get a ClassNotFoundException, so there is nothing left of your questioned to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to extract the content of the objects, however, this is not very convenient.

But, if you know what class to expect after deserialization, then you can cast down to the specific type.

Finding out the class of an object during runtime can be done like this:

```
Object obj = objStream.readObject();
Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
System.out.println(clazz.getName());
```

Let's say, if prints `x.y.Person`, then you can modify your program to use that concrete class:

```
import x.y.Person;

Person person = (Person) objStream.readObject();
System.out.println(person.getName());
```

In case the classes are not available, then you can try to use [jdeserialize](https://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize/source/checkout?repo=wiki) to extract the content of the serialization stream.

Comment: Well, when you wrote _I have managed to to read it with Javas ObjectInputStream_ I thought there was no error. You should include the error message in your question as well.

Comment: I didn't notice the error because the original code I used to test with used System.out.println for the error, which made me unaware that there was an error.

Comment: Is this still possible? Or must I have the original class in my source to do this?

Comment: @Louise and which class is missing?

Comment: It's a foreign class that I don't have, I do not have the original Class of this objects source code.

Comment: Yes it does. What am I suppose to do with it? (by the way I have decompiled the original source code for the object, it is helpful for me, but not for this question.)

Comment: If you're still interested, we can discuss here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36562/discussion-between-louie-and-katona

Answer (score 1):

Java's serialization API assumes that the types are available on deserialization. The [design](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) is dependent on this.

You *might* be able to use the [Grammar for the Stream Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258) to write your own parser for the API's types.

**There are circumstances in which there is no field information**.

For example, the following [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) type does not provide any field metadata and its internals are written as *blockdata*:

```
public class ContrivedType implements Serializable {
  public String foo;
  public int bar;

  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeObject(foo);
    if (foo != null) {
      out.writeInt(bar);
    }
  }

  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,
      ClassNotFoundException {
    foo = (String) in.readObject();
    bar = foo != null ? in.readInt() : 0;
  }
}
```

The structure of the type's data is encapsulated in the type itself.

*If the API has javadoc it should provide some information as part of the [serialized form](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/serialized-form.html) documentation.*